# Finding the highest and lowest numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

You are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number. I'm trying to solve this problem without using `Math.max()` or `Math.min()`.

This is my code so far:

```js
function highAndLow(nums){  
  
  let arr = nums.split(' ');
  let maxNum = arr[0];
  let minNum = arr[0];
  
  for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > maxNum) {
        maxNum = arr[i];
        console.log('Setting maxNum to '  + maxNum);
      }
    } 

    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i] < minNum) {
          minNum = arr[i];
          console.log('Setting minNum to '  + minNum);
       }  
    }
    const result = maxNum + " " + minNum;
    return result;
}
```

Expected: `542, -214`, instead got: `6, -214`

Why am I getting 6 instead of 542?

Comment: You need to convert the array elements to numbers. You're comparing them lexicographically.

Comment: Two comments: 1) You should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This means include a small test dataset that reproduces your error. It looks like the commenter above spotted the error regardless, but this is a good way to get answers to your question. 2) It's a good idea to just loop once and search for both the minimum and maximum number at the same time.

Comment: Like pointed out, your string comparing.  It's a bit like how  `Bob` comes after `Andy`, even though Andy is a longer string.

Comment: Start debugging.

Comment: I wrote a program that gives the day-of-the-month, and it also returns 6. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution turns out to be easier than expected:

```
 function highAndLow(nums){
   var array = nums.split(' ');

  var num = array.map(item => parseFloat(item));
  var sortedArray = num.sort((a, b) =>  b -a );
  console.log(sortedArray);
  return sortedArray[0] + ', ' + sortedArray.reverse()[0]
 }

 var result = highAndLow('2 3 9 3 50 32');
 console.log(result);
```

In this example you don´t use neither Math.max or Math.min

Comment: OP said without Math.max or Math.min

Comment: I´ve just fixed it

Comment: @Artofu this is slower than OP's ```O(N)``` solution

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean by "OP´s O(N)"